# MP4Box -dash-live how to deal with dash.js

Tags: mpeg-dash, mp4box, dash.js

I'm trying to get a pseudo live with mp4box and visualise it with dash.js inside apache or mamp, my os is sierra.
For my test i use a video already encoded of Simpsons http://www.h264info.com/clips.html,
cause i understand that the encode by ffmpeg is necessary only for multi bitrate purpose and for the moment i don't need it.
Osmo work fine, can read the manifest fast and well
Dash.js example works fine with theirs manifest link inside the html, but it can't works with my manifest. So i understand that Dash.js work.

COMMAND LINE:
sudo MP4Box -dash-live 1000 -frag 1000 -profile live -subdur 1000 -mpd-refresh 1000 -time-shift 16 -bs-switching no -segment-name output-seg -out manifest.mpd video_test.mp4

I use sudo cause I'm using osx but i believe that don't create any issue.
I try different browser, the dashifk conformance page.
I can't understand why on Mamp or Apache, the page can't visualise the manifest I'm generating for pseudo live use.
Where I'm wrong?
Could you help me?
Thanks!
Massimo

MANIFEST:

```html
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!-- MPD file Generated with GPAC version 0.7.2-DEV-rev358-g433fbcc3-master  at 2018-01-10T19:37:33.515Z-->
<MPD xmlns="urn:mpeg:dash:schema:mpd:2011" minBufferTime="PT1.500S" type="dynamic" publishTime="2018-01-10T19:37:33Z" availabilityStartTime="2018-01-10T19:28:35.335Z" timeShiftBufferDepth="PT0H1M4.000S" mediaPresentationDuration="PT0H0M16.227S" maxSegmentDuration="PT0H0M1.333S" profiles="urn:mpeg:dash:profile:isoff-live:2011">
 <ProgramInformation moreInformationURL="http://gpac.io">
  <Title>manifest.mpd generated by GPAC</Title>
 </ProgramInformation>

 <Period id="DID1" start="PT0H0M0.000S">
  <AdaptationSet segmentAlignment="true" maxWidth="320" maxHeight="240" maxFrameRate="15" par="4:3" lang="eng">
   <ContentComponent id="1" contentType="audio" />
   <ContentComponent id="2" contentType="video" />
   <SegmentTemplate media="output-seg$Number$.m4s" timescale="1000" startNumber="1" duration="1000" initialization="output-seginit.mp4"/>
   <Representation id="1" mimeType="video/mp4" codecs="mp4a.40.2,mp4v.20.2" width="320" height="240" frameRate="15" sar="1:1" startWithSAP="1" bandwidth="108411">
    <AudioChannelConfiguration schemeIdUri="urn:mpeg:dash:23003:3:audio_channel_configuration:2011" value="1"/>
   </Representation>
  </AdaptationSet>
 </Period>
</MPD>
```

THE BASIC HTML FOR TEST

```html
THE BASIC HTML FOR TEST

`<script src="https://cdn.dashjs.org/latest/dash.all.min.js"></script>
...
<style>
    video {
       width: 640px;
       height: 360px;
    }
</style>
...
<body>
   <div>
       <video data-dashjs-player autoplay src="manifest.mpd" controls></video>
   </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to add the flag -profile dashavc264:live if you want it to be compatible with dash.js player.

```
MP4Box -h dash
```